# Overriding function in imglib.js

Tags: 2010, development, javascript, picture-library

My question is regarding a default SharePoint imglib script. The script is located in following folder: 14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\imglib.js

The script has a function called: GenerateFooterContent(f, g).

Basically i want to override this method, and do some other stuff instead of the current.
Anyone has any idea how can i achieve that?

I've copied the whole function to my custom javascript file and i added it to the masterpage. But how can i say now that instead of default function my custom function should be used by the script?

On this [Link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/71a11a92-4b46-4c52-b008-9d83af10ad85) there is similar problem, but no solution is provided.

So can anyone give me a hint how to solve the problem?

UPDATE:

function to modify: function GenerateNFooterContent(f, g)  because it takes parameteres i have to call the above calling function

function ViewFooterScript() In this function i'll call the NEWGenerateNFooterContent

So here is the script which should override it, is it correct:

```
window.ViewFooterScript = function () {

    this.ViewFooterScript();
};
```

Althought it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use the [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects) (window) when you override it, like this:

```
var oldGenerateFooterContent = window.GenerateFooterContent;
window.GenerateFooterContent = function() {
  console.log('Hello, world!');
  // if you want you can call the old function here
  oldGenerateFooterContent();
};
```

**Update**:
If you want to provide the same arguments you can do that by calling [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).
like this:

```
oldGenerateFooterContent.apply(this, arguments);
// or
oldGenerateFooterContent.apply(null, arguments);
```

Comment: but is it ok that i do not provide the parameters?

Comment: Good call. Updated the answer, now I'm not sure if you should use `this`or not in apply

Comment: It is complicated: you see i want to modify in one script something, not add, but modify. But this function is called with paramteres which i do not have. So i decided to override the above calling function to call this function but modified version ... but hmm still not working

Comment: By copying the whole function as you did, and replacing window.GenerateFooterContent you should be good to go, simply run `console.log(arguments)` directly after if you wonder what arguments it is given

Comment: i modified the question, is this correct script which i run?

Comment: If you want a recursive endless function call, yes. But I don't think that is what you want

Comment: hmm how it should be then? :( not endless recursion

Answer (score 0):

You want to duck punch the function.

[Duck punching in javascript.](http://www.ericdelabar.com/2008/05/metaprogramming-javascript.html)

[Duck punching in JQuery](http://paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/)